# Why is my linked list empty with thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, linked-list

I have a linked list. When I am in the thread, my list is not empty and prints (for example) :

```
LISTE = Dan
LISTE = 4
```

And when I am in the wile(1) in the main(), the SAME list is empty and prints an empty line. The problem is that it doesn't enter in the "for". Do you have an idea of what the problem is ?

Thanks for your help.

PS : The sockets are not the problem

```
struct User {
  char pseudo[PSEUDO_MAX];
  int socket;
  struct User *next;
};


struct Thread {
  struct User* lst;
  fd_set* readfds;
  int* max;
  int socket;
  pthread_mutex_t* mutex;
};


void add(struct User** pp, const char *t, const int sock)
{
    struct User *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    strcpy(p->pseudo, t);
    p->socket = sock;
    p->next = NULL;

    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    *pp = p;
}


void print(const struct User* n) 
{
    for ( ; n; n = n->next ){
        printf("LISTE : %s\n", n->pseudo);
        printf("LISTE : %d\n", n->socket);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void *thread_pseudo(void *arg)
{
  struct Thread* ps_thread = (struct Thread*)arg;
  int nsock = ps_thread->socket;
  pthread_mutex_t* mutex = ps_thread->mutex;
  pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
  struct User* lst = ps_thread->lst;
  int* max = ps_thread->max;
  fd_set* readfds = ps_thread->readfds;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    // ...
    *max = (nsock < *max ? *max : nsock);

    // ...

    add(&lst, pseudo, nsock);

    print(lst); // HERE IT'S NOT EMPTY
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main()
{
  pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


  int sockfd2, new_fd;
  int max;
  struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
  struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
  unsigned int sin_size;
  int yes=1;
  struct User *lst = NULL;
  struct Thread *ps_thread = malloc(sizeof(*ps_thread));
  fd_set readfds;


  // ...



  while(1){
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd2, &readfds);
    print(lst); // HERE IT'S EMPTY

    //...
        pthread_t thread; 
        ps_thread->lst = lst;
        ps_thread->readfds = &readfds;
        ps_thread->max = &max;
        ps_thread->socket = new_fd;
        ps_thread->mutex = &mutex;

        if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_pseudo, ps_thread)) {
        perror("pthread_create");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Are you expecting `main()`'s `lst` to change when you change the thread's `lst`?  They're two different variables... copying the value of a pointer to another won't make the two stay the same when you modify one (if you're changing the value of the pointer rather than the data it points at).

Comment: I thought that because there were pointers, it would change, like max for example : max in the main and max in the thread remain the same.

So what can I do for `lst` to change in the main when `lst` is changed in the thread ?

Comment: You could add a level of indirection (use a pointer-to-pointer and dereference when accessing it), or use a global variable (only sometimes appropriate)... with proper synchronization (mutex) either way.  There are other ways as well... but you need to ensure any other pointers to the list get updated when you change one, and that access is synchronized properly.

Comment: Aren't you actually destroying your linked list in the `add` function? It seems to me that by using the original root pointer (instead of a temporary variable) to iterate to the end of the linked list, you are losing the head of the list and the root will always point to the last element of the list.